# Using foundation and HAML/SASS, how would you accomplish this?

Tags: html, css, sass, haml, zurb-foundation

[image: Arrows]

So I am using foundation, from zurb, and I am trying to accomplish the design for the image above. I have figured out a few different ways, but the most reliable way is simply something like this.

```
.large-2.columns
  %h3 Our Products
.large-10.columns
  .arrow
```

As you can see, this would make the arrow the same width for the Our products and About us sections. What I am looking for, is the most efficient way to make sure these needs are met:

- Arrow and h3 are variable width
- Quality of arrow doesn't change with variable width (the line/arrow/etc all have the same width)
- Preferably not have a TON of markup or a TON of sass.

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to change your title to something better, ie: how to create HR with an image prefix/suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the :before and :after pseudo-elements (together with content) to achieve this. Unless you need to support IE6/7, then you would have to do something more ugly I guess.

Remember that :before inserts content inside the targeted element (but before any child elements inside the target element, and the same goes for the :after element - just that it will inject content after any child elements). We can however still get away with only one hr element if we use absolute positioning.

**CSS:**

```
h3 {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  float: left;
}
hr {
  clear: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
}
hr:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red; /* can remove this, only for testing */
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-position: 0 0; /* set to correct pos for your sprites.gif background-image */
}
hr:after {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red; /* can remove this, only for testing */
  right: 0.9375em;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h3>OUR PRODUCTS</h3><hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use a background-image sprite for your arrows, and put in the correct x y coordinates. (the background-color: red is just to show that this works)